# SQL query for GROUP BY, return groups that match the conditions of LEAST, COALESCE

Tags: mysql, sql, r, group-by, rmysql

I want to write an SQL query calling for several columns with a bit complicated conditions. I'm working on R Studio using RMySQL package. My server is MySQL.

The table looks like this.

```
organisation    Tour_ID             A           B           C           D  
Ikea                  a    2018-04-01  2018-05-07  2018-05-09  2018-05-01
Ikea                  a    2018-06-01  2018-05-03  2018-05-29          NA   
Ikea                  a    2018-04-02  2018-05-01  2018-07-08  2018-05-26 
Ikea                  b    2018-06-02  2018-05-01          NA  2018-05-26
Ikea                  b    2018-06-02  2018-05-01          NA  2018-05-26
Ikea                  b            NA  2018-05-05  2018-08-02  2018-06-01
Ikea                  c    2018-06-01  2018-05-07  2018-05-09  2018-05-01
Ikea                  c    2018-06-01  2018-05-03          NA          NA   
Ikea                  c    2018-08-02  2018-05-09  2018-07-08  2018-05-26
```

This is what I want to do:

1. filter the rows where `organisation = Ikea`
2. groupby by `Tour_ID` like this:

   ```
   organisation    Tour_ID             A           B           C           D  
   Ikea                  a    2018-04-01  2018-05-07  2018-05-09  2018-05-01
   Ikea                  a    2018-06-01  2018-05-03  2018-05-29          NA   
   Ikea                  a    2018-04-02  2018-05-01  2018-07-08  2018-05-26 


   Ikea                  b    2018-06-02  2018-05-01          NA  2018-05-26
   Ikea                  b    2018-06-02  2018-05-01          NA  2018-05-26
   Ikea                  b            NA  2018-05-05  2018-08-02  2018-06-01


   Ikea                  c    2018-06-01  2018-05-07  2018-05-09  2018-05-01
   Ikea                  c    2018-06-01  2018-05-03          NA          NA   
   Ikea                  c    2018-08-02  2018-05-09  2018-07-08  2018-05-26
   ```
3. in each group of `Tour_ID`, look at the earliest date in columns `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`. If the earliest date among the four columns in the group is between `2018-05-01` and `2018-05-31`, return the entire group. If a row contains `NA` values, I want to ignore the `NA`s and see what's the earliest date among the rest of the values. For example, for the group of `Tour_ID = a`,  the earliest date is `2018-04-01` therefore it doesn't meet the criteria.

In conclusion, only the groups where `Tour_ID = b` and `Tour_ID = c` match the conditions. The result should be:

```
organisation    Tour_ID             A           B           C           D
Ikea                  b    2018-06-02  2018-05-01          NA  2018-05-26
Ikea                  b    2018-06-02  2018-05-01          NA  2018-05-26
Ikea                  b            NA  2018-05-05  2018-08-02  2018-06-01
Ikea                  c    2018-06-01  2018-05-07  2018-05-09  2018-05-01
Ikea                  c    2018-06-01  2018-05-03          NA          NA   
Ikea                  c    2018-08-02  2018-05-09  2018-07-08  2018-05-26
```

How should I write an SQL query?
Here is my attempt, but I just don't know how to do groupby, and how to return the entire group not just the rows with the earliest date.

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable 
WHERE organisation LIKE 'Ikea' AND
GROUP BY 'Tour_ID' AND
LEAST(COALESCE(A, '2019-01-01'), COALESCE(B, '2019-01-01'), COALESCE(C, '2019-01-01'), COALESCE(D, '2019-01-01')) >= '2018-05-01' AND
LEAST(COALESCE(A, '2019-01-01'), COALESCE(B, '2019-01-01'), COALESCE(C, '2019-01-01'), COALESCE(D, '2019-01-01')) < '2018-06-01';
```

('2019-01-01' is to replace NAs)

Thank you for any kinds of help!

ADDED:
Following the answer by [Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff), here I rewrote the SQL statement.

```
"SELECT t.* FROM myTable JOIN (SELECT organisation, Tour_ID 
                                                   FROM myTable
                                                   WHERE organisation LIKE 'Ikea' AND
                                                   GROUP BY organisation, Tour_ID
                                                   HAVING LEAST(COALESCE(MIN(A), '2119-01-01'), 
                                                                COALESCE(MIN(B), '2119-01-01'), 
                                                                COALESCE(MIN(C), '2119-01-01'), 
                                                                COALESCE(MIN(D), '2119-01-01')) >= '2018-05-01' AND
                                                          LEAST(COALESCE(MIN(A), '2119-01-01'), 
                                                                COALESCE(MIN(B), '2119-01-01'), 
                                                                COALESCE(MIN(C), '2119-01-01'), 
                                                                COALESCE(MIN(D), '2119-01-01')) < '2018-06-01'
                                                  ) tt
                                                  ON tt.Tour_ID = t.Tour_ID AND
                                                     tt.organisation = t.organisation"
```

And I ran `dbGetQuery` from RMySQL package. But I get the following error. I don't understand because `GROUP BY` part seems quite okay. Does anyone know why I'm getting this error?

```
dbGetQuery(connection = connection, statement = condition)

Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : could not run statement: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY organisation, Tour_ID HAVING LEAST(COALESCE(A' at line 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL query: GROUP BY, LEAST and return the entire group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51060255/sql-query-group-by-least-and-return-the-entire-group)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the `tour_id`s that match the conditions:

```
SELECT Tour_ID
FROM myTable 
WHERE organisation LIKE 'Ikea'
GROUP BY Tour_ID
HAVING LEAST(COALESCE(MIN(A), '2019-01-01'), COALESCE(MIN(B), '2019-01-01'), COALESCE(MIN(C), '2019-01-01'), COALESCE(MIN(D), '2019-01-01')) >= '2018-05-01' AND
       LEAST(COALESCE(MIN(A), '2019-01-01'), COALESCE(MIN(B), '2019-01-01'), COALESCE(MIN(C), '2019-01-01'), COALESCE(MIN(D), '2019-01-01')) < '2018-06-01';
```

Then put this into a query to get the original rows.  Here is one way:

```
select t.*
from mytable t join
     (SELECT organisation, Tour_ID
      FROM myTable 
      WHERE organisation LIKE 'Ikea'
      GROUP BY organisation, Tour_ID
      HAVING LEAST(COALESCE(MIN(A), '2019-01-01'), COALESCE(MIN(B), '2019-01-01'), COALESCE(MIN(C), '2019-01-01'), COALESCE(MIN(D), '2019-01-01')) >= '2018-05-01' AND
             LEAST(COALESCE(MIN(A), '2019-01-01'), COALESCE(MIN(B), '2019-01-01'), COALESCE(MIN(C), '2019-01-01'), COALESCE(MIN(D), '2019-01-01')) < '2018-06-01'
     ) tt
     ON tt.tour_id = t.tour_id AND
        tt.organisation = t.organisation;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! Why are there `MIN()` event though it already has `LEAST()`?

Comment: I followed your answer but it seems something is wrong with the syntax, which I cannot identify. I updated the question. Could you please take a look?

Comment: The `MIN()` is because of the aggregation.  I do not see any obvious syntax issue.