# RMySQL Syntax error unidentifiable

Tags: mysql, sql

This is continuous from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51079281/sql-query-for-group-by-return-groups-that-match-the-conditions-of-least-coales/51081209?noredirect=1#comment89175003_51081209). I'm using RMySQL package in R to send a SQL suery to the MySQL database. The error says something is wrong with the syntax, but I cannot find the error part. Could anybody help me fix this error?

The data table looks like this:

```
organisation    Tour_ID             A           B           C           D  
Ikea                  a    2018-04-01  2018-05-07  2018-05-09  2018-05-01
Ikea                  a    2018-06-01  2018-05-03  2018-05-29          NA   
Ikea                  a    2018-04-02  2018-05-01  2018-07-08  2018-05-26 
Ikea                  b    2018-06-02  2018-05-01          NA  2018-05-26
Ikea                  b    2018-06-02  2018-05-01          NA  2018-05-26
Ikea                  b            NA  2018-05-05  2018-08-02  2018-06-01
Ikea                  c    2018-06-01  2018-05-07  2018-05-09  2018-05-01
Ikea                  c    2018-06-01  2018-05-03          NA          NA   
Ikea                  c    2018-08-02  2018-05-09  2018-07-08  2018-05-26
```

And the syntax I wrote is:

```
cond <- 'SELECT t.* 
         FROM myTable t JOIN 
                        (SELECT organisation, Tour_ID 
                         FROM myTable 
                         WHERE organisation LIKE "Ikea" AND
                         GROUP BY organisation, Tour_ID 
                         HAVING LEAST(COALESCE(MIN(A), "2119-01-01"),
                                      COALESCE(MIN(B), "2119-01-01"),
                                      COALESCE(MIN(C), "2119-01-01"), 
                                      COALESCE(MIN(D), "2119-01-01")) >= "2018-05-01 00:00" AND 
                                LEAST(COALESCE(MIN(A), "2119-01-01"), 
                                      COALESCE(MIN(B), "2119-01-01"),
                                      COALESCE(MIN(C), "2119-01-01"),
                                      COALESCE(MIN(D), "2119-01-01")) < "2018-05-31 00:00"
                         ) tt ON 
                           tt.Tour_ID = t.Tour_ID AND 
                           tt.organisation = t.organisation'

dbGetQuery(conn = connection, statement = cond)
```

And the error message I get is:

```
Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : could not run statement: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax 
to use near 'GROUP BY organisation, Tour_ID HAVING LEAST(COALESCE(MIN(A' at line 1
```

But I see no issue at GROUP BY part! What's wrong with my syntax?

Comment: `WHERE organisation LIKE "Ikea" AND GROUP BY organisation` makes no sense. Remove `AND` before `GROUP BY` ...

Comment: Also, you missed the ending mysql `;` after `t.organisation`.

Comment: yours was totally correct. Thank you very much!