# RMySQL: SQL Syntax error unidentifiable

Tags: mysql, sql, r, syntax, having

This is continuous from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51079281/sql-query-for-group-by-return-groups-that-match-the-conditions-of-least-coales/51081209?noredirect=1#comment89175003_51081209). I'm using RMySQL package in R to send a SQL suery to the MySQL database. The error says something is wrong with the syntax, but I cannot find the error part. Could anybody help me fix this error?

The data table looks like this:

```
organisation    Tour_ID             A           B           C           D  
Ikea                  a    2018-04-01  2018-05-07  2018-05-09  2018-05-01
Ikea                  a    2018-06-01  2018-05-03  2018-05-29          NA   
Ikea                  a    2018-04-02  2018-05-01  2018-07-08  2018-05-26 
Ikea                  b    2018-06-02  2018-05-01          NA  2018-05-26
Ikea                  b    2018-06-02  2018-05-01          NA  2018-05-26
Ikea                  b            NA  2018-05-05  2018-08-02  2018-06-01
Ikea                  c    2018-06-01  2018-05-07  2018-05-09  2018-05-01
Ikea                  c    2018-06-01  2018-05-03          NA          NA   
Ikea                  c    2018-08-02  2018-05-09  2018-07-08  2018-05-26
```

And the syntax I wrote is:

```
cond <- "SELECT t.* FROM myTable t JOIN  
                                   (SELECT organisation, Tour_ID, 
                                    FROM myTable WHERE organisation LIKE "Ikea"  
                                    GROUP BY organisation, Tour_ID 
                                    HAVING A >= \"2018-05-01 00:00\" AND 
                                           A < \"2018-05-31 00:00 \"
                                   ) tt ON 
                                     tt.Tour_ID = t.Tour_ID AND 
                                     tt.organisation = t.organisation"

dbGetQuery(conn = connection, statement = cond)
```

And the error message I get is:

```
Unknown column 'A' in 'having clause'
```

But I see no issue at HAVING part! What's wrong with my syntax?
Also if I add A in `SELECT` clause, the error message reads:

```
Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
could not run statement: Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause 
and contains nonaggregated column 'myTable.myTable.A' 
which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; 
this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear what you want.  But columns in the `HAVING` have to either be in the `GROUP BY` or arguments to aggregations.  Perhaps you want:

```
(SELECT organisation, Tour_ID
 FROM myTable WHERE organisation LIKE "Ikea"  
 GROUP BY organisation, Tour_ID 
 HAVING MIN(A) >= '2018-05-01' AND 
        MAX(A) < '2018-05-31'
) tt
```

Single quotes should be used for date constants.  I speculate that the second constant should be `'2018-06-01'`, if you want a range for all dates in May.